# Notify delivery callbacks sid property

Tags: c#, twilio

Have a question for twilio api.

As far as i can see when i create a notification resource you can specify a delivery callback where you can be notified about all notification statuses that were sent.

Twilio [docs](https://www.twilio.com/docs/notify/notify-delivery-callbacks) specify the object that one can fetch from webhook is this one

[image]

My question is what exactly is **sid** property.

I would expect it to be the sid property returned when you create a binding resource ([link](https://www.twilio.com/docs/notify/api/binding-resource)) but its a different form (sid from webhook is a Guid but sid from binding resource response is in BSXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX format).

The thing i am trying to achieve is get the sid from webhook and then if it has status FAILED to remove binding from my db (which has different sid format).

Is there sth i am missing?

Answer (score 0):

The Sid in the webhook is the Sid of the message itself. This can either be an Message Sid (which starts with SM for SMS or MM for MMS, or RU for other adapters) or the ID of the push notification from APNS or FCM. You are also provided the type of the messages (SMS, APN, FCM, etc) and the identity of the user. Between the type and identity you should be able to determine the binding by [listing the bindings for an identity](https://www.twilio.com/docs/notify/api/binding-resource#read-multiple-binding-resources) and matching the `BindingType` or filtering by the implicit tag for the channel type.

Comment: Thanks for the reply! Still i dont get it though. The webhook sid is not in BSXXXX format but a simple Guid. There is no correlation to the bindings i have in my database. Sure i get the type and identity of the binding but i cannot determine which exact binding it is dut to different sid values (and formats).

Comment: The webhook does not give you the SID of the binding, I'm afraid. Are you sending the notification to multiple bindings of the same type (APN/FCM) within the same Notification?

Comment: Yes the notification has many FCM  bindings. And i want to know which specific binding has failed to receive the notification. So it is not possible?

Comment: I don't believe that is possible, no.

Comment: Last question :) Sometimes if a notification is not delivered, twilio removes the binding automatically. Is there a way to get notified whenever this happens? Because this way there may be occasions that i have registered in my db a bunch of binding that are invalid.

Comment: You get notified by the same webhook, but based on the error that happens. It's only when an [unrecoverable error is triggered, and those are listed in the docs here](https://www.twilio.com/docs/notify/api/notification-resource#unrecoverable-channel-errors).